# How to receive bot's messages in telegram?

Tags: node.js, web, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I wrote some bot that sends messages to some channel using nodejs. This bot is an admin in that channel and it can see messages from users using /getupdates api. However it can't see own messages. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: use the callback or promise of your sendMessage api to save the sent message

Comment: But I don't want to save it to my database. I just want to get it as messages from another users.